# Is there a pattern for data synchronization in two independent services?

Tags: java, synchronization

I need the data in the two services to be identical. Changes can be made to each of the services at the same time. I made integration with each service using the REST API. But here's what and how to track and what are the options for resolving data conflicts. For example, Google calendar events and some task Manager, such as Todoist (I know that there is a built-in integration :) )

Answer (score 0):

When `Service1` has an update, then `Service1` publishes a message to a topic.  `Service2` is subscribed to the topic, receives the message, and `Service2` updates its data. `Service2` doesn't know that the message originated from `Service1`.

Similarly, when `Service2` has an update, then `Service2` publishes a message to the same topic.  `Service1` is subscribed to the topic, receives the message, and `Service1` updates its data. `Service1` doesn't know that the message originated from `Service2`.

This is referred to as a publish-subscribe pattern, and is near real-time, where synchronization depends on the backlog of messages to be processed.  It depends on the app, but a few milliseconds of being out of sync is usually acceptable for a human user.

Comment: Thanks. in General, this is now done, but I thought there was some pattern of storing synchronization information in a certain way. What are the options for resolving collisions in modified data in both systems? How can I check for changed data, for example, using etag?
To clarify, both services are external to me, working with them only via the Rest Api.

Comment: It should depend on the message broker (not the consumer), where the message broker provides a FIFO topic.